# How to scrape two tables and write to one csv?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the two tables on this website: https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/latest-news-and-updates

At this stage I'm blocked just getting an initial output. My scraper isn't returning any errors so I can't see the problem.

Ideally I'd like to combine the two tables into one, with an additional column for Action and a value for the title of the table (example is below).

This is this code I've tried to use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from csv import writer

url = 'https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/latest-news-and-updates'

r = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


tables = soup.find_all('nsw-table-responsive')

for num, table in enumerate(tables, start=1):

    filename = 'covidstatus.csv' % num

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:

        data = []

        csv_writer = writer(f)

        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:

            headers = row.find_all('th')
            if headers:
                csv_writer.writerow([header.text.strip() for header in headers])

            columns = row.find_all('td')
            csv_writer.writerow([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
```

Below is an example of my ideal output

```
Location,Dates,Action
Glebe: Jambo Jambo African Restaurant,7pm to 10:30pm on Friday 31 July 2020,Self-isolate and get tested immediately
Hamilton: Bennett Hotel,5:30pm to 10pm on Friday 31 July,Self-isolate and get tested immediately
Bankstown: BBQ City Buffet,7pm to 8.30pm on Saturday 1 August,Monitor for symptoms
Broadmeadow: McDonald Jones Stadium,7:30pm to the end of the Newcastle Jets match on Sunday 2 August,Monitor for symptoms
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer with this.

Comment: If you can use pandas, ``pd.concat(pd.read_html('<url>')).to_csv('<csv_path>')``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script saves the data to `data.csv`:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/latest-news-and-updates'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
    all_data.append(
        [td.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n') for td in row.select('td')]
    )
    all_data[-1].append(row.find_previous('h4').text)
    all_data[-1][0] = all_data[-1][0].replace('\n', '')

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Screenshot of `data.csv` from LibreOffice:

[image]

---

EDIT: (To write headings):

```
...

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Location', 'Dates', 'Type'])
    for row in all_data:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. What's the simplest way to write in the column headings (th) ?

Comment: thanks!! I'd actually like to add one more thing to it, but this might be tricky. The tables are updated pretty often. I'd like to add an additional 'status' column with 'active' or 'inactive as a value to capture historical data. So when a row is removed from the table, it remains in the csv output and gains the 'inactive value'. Would something like that be achievable?

Comment: @krazykrejza Yes, it's achievable. You can treat the CSV as database (with fourth column "Active"): Load the CSV at the beginning, then load data from the web and compare them. Set the data loaded from the web as Active, everything else as Inactive. Save the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code let me know if you have questions

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from requests import get
 from csv import writer

 url = 'https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/latest-news-and-updates'

 r = get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


 tables = soup.find_all('table')

 for num, table in enumerate(tables, start=1):

     filename = 'covidstatus.csv'


     with open(filename, 'w') as f:

         data = []

         csv_writer = writer(f)

         rows = table.find_all('tr')
         for row in rows:

             headers = row.find_all('th')
             if headers:
                 head = [header.text.strip() for header in headers]
                 print(head)
                 csv_writer.writerow([header.text.strip() for header in headers])

             columns = row.find_all('td')
             print([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
             csv_writer.writerow([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
```

here is the output

```
['Location', 'Dates']
[]
['Hamilton: Sydney Junction Hotel', '11pm on Saturday 1 August to 1:15am on Sunday 2 August']
['Huskisson: Wildginger', '7:45pm to 10:30pm on Saturday 8 August']
['Lidcombe: Dooleys Lidcombe Catholic Club', '5pm on Friday 7 August to 6:30am on Saturday 8 August\xa0\n\t\t\t4:30pm to 11:30pm on Saturday 8 August\n\t\t\t1pm to 9pm on Sunday 9 August\n\t\t\t12pm to 9:30pm on Monday 10 August\xa0\nIf you were at this venue for at least 1 hour during any of these
times, you must self-isolate and get tested and stay isolated for 14 days after your last day at the venue within these dates. (Advice updated 16\xa0August)']
['Mollymook: Rick Stein at Bannisters', '8pm to 10:30pm on Saturday 1 August for at least one hour\nSelf-isolate until midnight 15 August or until you have received a negative result, whichever is later.']
['New Lambton: Bar 88 - Wests New Lambton', '5pm to 7:15pm on Sunday 2 August']
['Newcastle: Hamilton to Adamstown Number 26 bus', '8:20am on Monday 3 August']
['Location', 'Dates']
[]
[]
['Bowral:\xa0Horderns Restaurant at Milton Park Country House Hotel and Spa', '7:45pm to 9:15pm on\xa0Sunday 2 August']
['Broadmeadow: McDonald Jones Stadium', '7:30pm to the end of the Newcastle Jets match on Sunday 2 August']
['Campbelltown: Bunnings Warehouse', '11am to 7pm on Tuesday 4 August\xa0\n\t\t\t8am to 4pm on Wednesday 5 August\n\t\t\t1pm to 3pm on Thursday 6 August']
['Castle Hill:\xa0Castle Towers Shopping Centre', '3:30pm to 5pm on Friday\xa07 August']
['Cherrybrook:\xa0PharmaSave Cherrybrook Pharmacy in Appletree Shopping Centre', '4pm to 7pm on Thursday 6 August']
['Concord:\xa0Crust Pizza', '4pm to\xa08pm on\xa0Thursday 6 August\n\t\t\t5pm to 9pm on\xa0Friday 7 August']
['Double Bay:\xa0Café Perons', '1pm to 2pm on\xa0Saturday 8 August']
['Liverpool:\xa0Liverpool Hospital', '7am to 3pm on Thursday 6 August\n\t\t\t7am to 3pm on Friday 7 August\n\t\t\t5am to 1:30pm on Saturday 8 August\n\t\t\t5am to 1:30pm on Sunday 9 August']
['Liverpool: Westfield Liverpool', '10:30am to 11am and 12:30pm to 1pm on Friday 7 August']
['Marrickville: Woolworths -\xa0Marrickville Metro Shopping Centre', '7pm to 7:20pm on Sunday 2 August']
['Parramatta: Westfield Parramatta', '4pm to 5:30pm on Wednesday\xa05 August\n\t\t\t12pm to 1pm on Saturday 8 August']
['Pennant Hills: St Agatha's', '6:30 am to 7am on\xa0Wednesday 5 August\n\t\t\t6:30 am to 7am on Thursday 6 August']
['Penrith: Baby Bunting', '1:15pm to 1:45pm on Saturday 8 August']
['Rhodes: IKEA', '1:20pm to 2:20pm on Saturday 8 August']
['Rose Bay:\xa0Den Sushi', '7:15pm to 8:45pm on\xa0Saturday 8 August']
['Smithfield:\xa0Chopstix Asian Cuisine, Smithfield RSL', 'Friday 31 July to Saturday 9 August']
['Wetherill Park: 5th Avenue Beauty Bar', '2pm to 3pm\xa0on Saturday 8 August']

In [81]:
```

Comment: This is helpful. Unfortunately the csv output is quite a bit different to the print. The first table (beginning row 3 in the print you posted) doesn't output at all, and there's additional characters (spaces) creating blank rows

Comment: Can you share the output you are getting in csv here ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `.read_html` from `Pandas`. Pandas will do the `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` for you:

```py
import pandas as pd

URI = 'https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/latest-news-and-updates'

# get tables
tables = pd.read_html(URI)

t1 = tables[0]
t2 = tables[1].dropna(axis=0)

# append tables
t = t1.append(t2, ignore_index=True)

# send tables to csv file
t.to_csv('my_table.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

You might have to install `lxml, html5lib` as Pandas’ `.read_html` needs these dependences.

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to learn more on pandas. I have both libs installed but got this problem
```
Double Bay:Â CafÃ© Perons 1pm to 2pm onÂ Saturday 8 August
Liverpool:Â Liverpool Hospital 7am to 3pm on Thursday 6 August  7am to 3pm on Friday 7 August  5am to 1:30pm on Saturday 8 August  5am to 1:30pm on Sunday 9 August
```

Comment: Ah, that looks like encoding issue in `.to_csv`. I will update my answer. Pandas is really handy if you want to process your data afterwards or send it to different formats such as Database, Hive etc :)

Comment: Try `utf-8` or `latin1`. I will test them when on PC. BTW, which Python version are you using?